# Combine Three Dataframes of Different Lengths

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join, merge

I apologize in advance for the length of this.  I am trying to combine three dataframes of different lengths and running into an issue.  I have been merging the first two dataframes together and then merging the third dataframe into that one.

This is the first dataframe:

```
                                  id      home team        away team           start time                 site home spread away spread home odds away odds
0   658e6acd85f15c5da10e271d25835b1b  Brooklyn Nets  Milwaukee Bucks  2021-06-07 19:40:00              FanDuel         2.0        -2.0      -114      -106
1   658e6acd85f15c5da10e271d25835b1b  Brooklyn Nets  Milwaukee Bucks  2021-06-07 19:40:00            BetRivers         1.5        -1.5      -110      -112
2   658e6acd85f15c5da10e271d25835b1b  Brooklyn Nets  Milwaukee Bucks  2021-06-07 19:40:00               Unibet         1.5        -1.5      -110      -111
3   658e6acd85f15c5da10e271d25835b1b  Brooklyn Nets  Milwaukee Bucks  2021-06-07 19:40:00  Barstool Sportsbook         1.5        -1.5      -110      -112
4   658e6acd85f15c5da10e271d25835b1b  Brooklyn Nets  Milwaukee Bucks  2021-06-07 19:40:00           SugarHouse         1.5        -1.5      -110      -112
5   658e6acd85f15c5da10e271d25835b1b  Brooklyn Nets  Milwaukee Bucks  2021-06-07 19:40:00           DraftKings         1.5        -1.5      -110      -112
6   658e6acd85f15c5da10e271d25835b1b  Brooklyn Nets  Milwaukee Bucks  2021-06-07 19:40:00               BetMGM         2.0        -2.0      -105      -115
7   658e6acd85f15c5da10e271d25835b1b  Brooklyn Nets  Milwaukee Bucks  2021-06-07 19:40:00         BetOnline.ag         2.0        -2.0      -111      -111
8   658e6acd85f15c5da10e271d25835b1b  Brooklyn Nets  Milwaukee Bucks  2021-06-07 19:40:00            LowVig.ag           2          -2      -107      -103
9   658e6acd85f15c5da10e271d25835b1b  Brooklyn Nets  Milwaukee Bucks  2021-06-07 19:40:00    William Hill (US)         2.0        -2.0      -110      -110
10  658e6acd85f15c5da10e271d25835b1b  Brooklyn Nets  Milwaukee Bucks  2021-06-07 19:40:00       PointsBet (US)         1.5        -1.5      -110      -110
11  658e6acd85f15c5da10e271d25835b1b  Brooklyn Nets  Milwaukee Bucks  2021-06-07 19:40:00               Bovada         1.5        -1.5      -105      -115
12  658e6acd85f15c5da10e271d25835b1b  Brooklyn Nets  Milwaukee Bucks  2021-06-07 19:40:00               GTbets         1.5        -1.5      -109      -109
13  658e6acd85f15c5da10e271d25835b1b  Brooklyn Nets  Milwaukee Bucks  2021-06-07 19:40:00            Intertops        2.00       -2.00      -115      -105
14  658e6acd85f15c5da10e271d25835b1b  Brooklyn Nets  Milwaukee Bucks  2021-06-07 19:40:00          MyBookie.ag         0.0         0.0      -110      -110
15  658e6acd85f15c5da10e271d25835b1b  Brooklyn Nets  Milwaukee Bucks  2021-06-07 19:40:00              Caesars         2.0        -2.0      -110      -110
```

This is the second one:

```
                                  id      home team        away team           start time                 site  total over line under line
0   658e6acd85f15c5da10e271d25835b1b  Brooklyn Nets  Milwaukee Bucks  2021-06-07 19:40:00              FanDuel  238.5      -114       -106
1   658e6acd85f15c5da10e271d25835b1b  Brooklyn Nets  Milwaukee Bucks  2021-06-07 19:40:00            BetRivers  238.0      -113       -109
2   658e6acd85f15c5da10e271d25835b1b  Brooklyn Nets  Milwaukee Bucks  2021-06-07 19:40:00               Unibet    238      -112       -109
3   658e6acd85f15c5da10e271d25835b1b  Brooklyn Nets  Milwaukee Bucks  2021-06-07 19:40:00  Barstool Sportsbook  238.0      -113       -109
4   658e6acd85f15c5da10e271d25835b1b  Brooklyn Nets  Milwaukee Bucks  2021-06-07 19:40:00           SugarHouse  238.0      -113       -109
5   658e6acd85f15c5da10e271d25835b1b  Brooklyn Nets  Milwaukee Bucks  2021-06-07 19:40:00           DraftKings    238      -113       -109
6   658e6acd85f15c5da10e271d25835b1b  Brooklyn Nets  Milwaukee Bucks  2021-06-07 19:40:00               BetMGM  237.5      -115       -105
7   658e6acd85f15c5da10e271d25835b1b  Brooklyn Nets  Milwaukee Bucks  2021-06-07 19:40:00         BetOnline.ag    238      -115       -105
8   658e6acd85f15c5da10e271d25835b1b  Brooklyn Nets  Milwaukee Bucks  2021-06-07 19:40:00            LowVig.ag    238      -110        100
9   658e6acd85f15c5da10e271d25835b1b  Brooklyn Nets  Milwaukee Bucks  2021-06-07 19:40:00    William Hill (US)    238      -110       -110
10  658e6acd85f15c5da10e271d25835b1b  Brooklyn Nets  Milwaukee Bucks  2021-06-07 19:40:00       PointsBet (US)    238      -115       -105
11  658e6acd85f15c5da10e271d25835b1b  Brooklyn Nets  Milwaukee Bucks  2021-06-07 19:40:00               Bovada    238      -115       -105
12  658e6acd85f15c5da10e271d25835b1b  Brooklyn Nets  Milwaukee Bucks  2021-06-07 19:40:00            Bookmaker    238      -110       -110
13  658e6acd85f15c5da10e271d25835b1b  Brooklyn Nets  Milwaukee Bucks  2021-06-07 19:40:00            Intertops    238      -110       -110
14  658e6acd85f15c5da10e271d25835b1b  Brooklyn Nets  Milwaukee Bucks  2021-06-07 19:40:00          MyBookie.ag  237.5      -110       -110
```

I have been merging them using `x_df =pd.merge(xo,xt,how='left',left_on=['id','home team','away team','start time','site'],right_on=['id','home team','away team','start time','site'])`

The result is:

```
                                  id      home team        away team           start time                 site home spread away spread home odds away odds  total over line under line
0   658e6acd85f15c5da10e271d25835b1b  Brooklyn Nets  Milwaukee Bucks  2021-06-07 19:40:00              FanDuel         2.0        -2.0      -114      -106  238.5      -114       -106
1   658e6acd85f15c5da10e271d25835b1b  Brooklyn Nets  Milwaukee Bucks  2021-06-07 19:40:00            BetRivers         1.5        -1.5      -110      -112  238.0      -113       -109
2   658e6acd85f15c5da10e271d25835b1b  Brooklyn Nets  Milwaukee Bucks  2021-06-07 19:40:00               Unibet         1.5        -1.5      -110      -111    238      -112       -109
3   658e6acd85f15c5da10e271d25835b1b  Brooklyn Nets  Milwaukee Bucks  2021-06-07 19:40:00  Barstool Sportsbook         1.5        -1.5      -110      -112  238.0      -113       -109
4   658e6acd85f15c5da10e271d25835b1b  Brooklyn Nets  Milwaukee Bucks  2021-06-07 19:40:00           SugarHouse         1.5        -1.5      -110      -112  238.0      -113       -109
5   658e6acd85f15c5da10e271d25835b1b  Brooklyn Nets  Milwaukee Bucks  2021-06-07 19:40:00           DraftKings         1.5        -1.5      -110      -112    238      -113       -109
6   658e6acd85f15c5da10e271d25835b1b  Brooklyn Nets  Milwaukee Bucks  2021-06-07 19:40:00               BetMGM         2.0        -2.0      -105      -115  237.5      -115       -105
7   658e6acd85f15c5da10e271d25835b1b  Brooklyn Nets  Milwaukee Bucks  2021-06-07 19:40:00         BetOnline.ag         2.0        -2.0      -111      -111    238      -115       -105
8   658e6acd85f15c5da10e271d25835b1b  Brooklyn Nets  Milwaukee Bucks  2021-06-07 19:40:00            LowVig.ag           2          -2      -107      -103    238      -110        100
9   658e6acd85f15c5da10e271d25835b1b  Brooklyn Nets  Milwaukee Bucks  2021-06-07 19:40:00    William Hill (US)         2.0        -2.0      -110      -110    238      -110       -110
10  658e6acd85f15c5da10e271d25835b1b  Brooklyn Nets  Milwaukee Bucks  2021-06-07 19:40:00       PointsBet (US)         1.5        -1.5      -110      -110    238      -115       -105
11  658e6acd85f15c5da10e271d25835b1b  Brooklyn Nets  Milwaukee Bucks  2021-06-07 19:40:00               Bovada         1.5        -1.5      -105      -115    238      -115       -105
12  658e6acd85f15c5da10e271d25835b1b  Brooklyn Nets  Milwaukee Bucks  2021-06-07 19:40:00               GTbets         1.5        -1.5      -109      -109    NaN       NaN        NaN
13  658e6acd85f15c5da10e271d25835b1b  Brooklyn Nets  Milwaukee Bucks  2021-06-07 19:40:00            Intertops        2.00       -2.00      -115      -105    238      -110       -110
14  658e6acd85f15c5da10e271d25835b1b  Brooklyn Nets  Milwaukee Bucks  2021-06-07 19:40:00          MyBookie.ag         0.0         0.0      -110      -110  237.5      -110       -110
15  658e6acd85f15c5da10e271d25835b1b  Brooklyn Nets  Milwaukee Bucks  2021-06-07 19:40:00              Caesars         2.0        -2.0      -110      -110    NaN       NaN        NaN
```

There are sites in the first dataframe that there are not in the second and vice-versa.  There should being `nulls` on both the spread and total sides.  I think the dataframe should also have more rows.

This is the third dataframe:

```
                                  id      home team        away team           start time                 site home line away line
0   658e6acd85f15c5da10e271d25835b1b  Brooklyn Nets  Milwaukee Bucks  2021-06-07 19:45:00              FanDuel       108      -126
1   658e6acd85f15c5da10e271d25835b1b  Brooklyn Nets  Milwaukee Bucks  2021-06-07 19:45:00            BetRivers       102      -121
2   658e6acd85f15c5da10e271d25835b1b  Brooklyn Nets  Milwaukee Bucks  2021-06-07 19:45:00               Unibet       102      -120
3   658e6acd85f15c5da10e271d25835b1b  Brooklyn Nets  Milwaukee Bucks  2021-06-07 19:45:00  Barstool Sportsbook       102      -121
4   658e6acd85f15c5da10e271d25835b1b  Brooklyn Nets  Milwaukee Bucks  2021-06-07 19:45:00           SugarHouse       102      -121
5   658e6acd85f15c5da10e271d25835b1b  Brooklyn Nets  Milwaukee Bucks  2021-06-07 19:45:00           DraftKings       102      -121
6   658e6acd85f15c5da10e271d25835b1b  Brooklyn Nets  Milwaukee Bucks  2021-06-07 19:45:00               BetMGM       110      -135
7   658e6acd85f15c5da10e271d25835b1b  Brooklyn Nets  Milwaukee Bucks  2021-06-07 19:45:00         BetOnline.ag       106      -127
8   658e6acd85f15c5da10e271d25835b1b  Brooklyn Nets  Milwaukee Bucks  2021-06-07 19:45:00            LowVig.ag       106      -126
9   658e6acd85f15c5da10e271d25835b1b  Brooklyn Nets  Milwaukee Bucks  2021-06-07 19:45:00              Betfair       114      -116
10  658e6acd85f15c5da10e271d25835b1b  Brooklyn Nets  Milwaukee Bucks  2021-06-07 19:45:00    William Hill (US)       105      -125
11  658e6acd85f15c5da10e271d25835b1b  Brooklyn Nets  Milwaukee Bucks  2021-06-07 19:45:00       PointsBet (US)       105      -125
12  658e6acd85f15c5da10e271d25835b1b  Brooklyn Nets  Milwaukee Bucks  2021-06-07 19:45:00               Bovada       105      -125
13  658e6acd85f15c5da10e271d25835b1b  Brooklyn Nets  Milwaukee Bucks  2021-06-07 19:45:00               GTbets       101      -129
14  658e6acd85f15c5da10e271d25835b1b  Brooklyn Nets  Milwaukee Bucks  2021-06-07 19:45:00            Bookmaker       100      -120
15  658e6acd85f15c5da10e271d25835b1b  Brooklyn Nets  Milwaukee Bucks  2021-06-07 19:45:00            Intertops       105      -125
16  658e6acd85f15c5da10e271d25835b1b  Brooklyn Nets  Milwaukee Bucks  2021-06-07 19:45:00          MyBookie.ag       105      -125
17  658e6acd85f15c5da10e271d25835b1b  Brooklyn Nets  Milwaukee Bucks  2021-06-07 19:45:00              Caesars       110      -130
```

There are sites in the third dataframe that are not in the other two dataframes.

When I try to merge it with the other merged dataframe using `x_df2 =pd.merge(xh,x_df,how='inner',left_on=['id','home team','away team','start time','site'],right_on=['id','home team','away team','start time','site'])` the results is an empty dataframe.

What is the best way to combine these three dataframes?  Thank you in advance.

Comment: I wonder what is the point in `id` column if it's not unique?

Comment: These part of larger dataframes.  I just showed you one set of games for illustration purposes.  The full dataframes are 57, 58 and 65 rows respectively.  The empty dataframe issue only happens when I have been experimenting with using these smaller dataframes of just one game.  When try to link the full dataframes, linking the third one retains only 41 rows.  I think it should be showing around 70 rows after all three are merged.

Comment: I guess you need to use `how = 'outer'` in order to get all the rows from both the dataframes

Comment: I need to test it out more but it looks like switching to ```outer``` fixes things. Is there an easier/cleaner/more elegant way to combine the three dataframes other than merging two of them together and then merging the third one onto that one?

Comment: Yes, you'll need to use `'outer'` join. When you do a `'left'`, it'll keep rows in the first dataframe if there's a match, and thus throw away whatever didn't match on the second dataframe. If you did a '`right'`, you'd only keep relevant rows in the 2nd dataframe. `'inner'` would only keep rows that have a match in both (throwing away any rows that would end up with a `null`). And `'outer'` will keep all rows from both dataframe, regardless of a match on the keys.